# How to test GetParameter of SSM using aws-sdk-client-mock in typescript

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk-js, aws-ssm, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-sdk-mock

I want to write test case for SSM GetParameterCommand request in typescript. My code looks like:

```
const region = "us-east-1"
const awsSSMClient = new SSMClient({ region })

export async function fetchParam(parameterName: string, decrypt: boolean): Promise<string> {
    const paramconfig = {
        Name: parameterName,
        WithDecryption: decrypt
    }

    const command = new GetParameterCommand(input)
    const parameter: any = await awsSSMClient.send(command)

    return parameter.Parameter.Value
}
```

Can I use aws-sdk-client-mock? If not can anyone provide me an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `aws-sdk-client-mock` for this. For the code snippet you have provided your test case would look something like this:

```
jest.mock("aws-sdk-client-mock-jest");
const {SSMClient, GetParameterCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/client-ssm");
const {mockClient} = require("aws-sdk-client-mock");

test("Param is returned", async () => {
    const ssmMock = mockClient(SSMClient);
    ssmMock.on(GetParameterCommand).resolves({
            Parameter: {
            Value: "Whatever you want to return"
        }
    });
    const result = await fetchParam();
    
    // Make your assertions
});
```